# How to return key value pair array in res.json() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am generating a key-value pair array in my code, but when I pass the array in `res.json()` I am receiving null on front-end.

This is the key-value array that I want to pass. Any Idea what I am not doing right?

```
router.post('/xlsData',  session, async (req, res)=>{

    const reqStatus = req.body.searchType;
    const reportDate = req.body.reportDate;
    const userBebitReq = await debitReq.find({ reqStatus : reqStatus,  reqType: "Debit", reqDate : reportDate},{_id : 1, userId: 1,reqAmount : 1, withdrawalMode: 1, reqDate: 1, });
    let userIdArray = [];
    let debitArray = [];
    for(index in userBebitReq)
    {
        let reqAmount= userBebitReq[index].reqAmount;
        let withdrawalMode= userBebitReq[index].withdrawalMode;
        let reqDate= userBebitReq[index].reqDate;
        let user = userBebitReq[index].userId;
        let rowId = userBebitReq[index]._id;
        let userKi = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(user);
        userIdArray.push(userKi);
        debitArray[userKi] = {
            rowId : rowId,
            userId : userKi,
            reqAmount: reqAmount,
            withdrawalMode: withdrawalMode,
            reqDate: reqDate
        }
    }

    let user_Profile = await userProfile.find({ userId: { $in: userIdArray } });

    for(index in user_Profile)
    {
        let id = user_Profile[index].userId;
        if(debitArray[id]){
            debitArray[id].address = user_Profile[index].address;
            debitArray[id].city = user_Profile[index].city;
            debitArray[id].pincode = user_Profile[index].pincode;
            debitArray[id].name = user_Profile[index].account_holder_name;
            debitArray[id].account_no = user_Profile[index].account_no;
            debitArray[id].bank_name = user_Profile[index].bank_name;
            debitArray[id].ifsc = user_Profile[index].ifsc_code;
            debitArray[id].paytm_number = user_Profile[index].paytm_number;
        }
    }

    res.json({
        status : 1,
        data : debitArray
    })  
})
```

Receiving this on front-end : 
    `data: Array(0)`

Comment: Did you try debugging ? Because this should do the work

Comment: yes i have tried got no error in debugging

Comment: is res.json() line executed after all above operations are done? I think maybe an issue of asynchronous behavior

Comment: got answer below, and i guess no problem with asynchronous thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
let debitArray = {};
```

instead of this.

```
let debitArray = [];
```

You are basically using **object** not **array**.